# it says 'comparison of Fixnum with nil failed' and i dont know why

Tags: ruby

```
A = [5,3,1,4,2]

4.downto(1) do |i|
  0.upto(i) do |j|
    #here i am making the actual buble sort

    if A[j] > A[j + 1]
      tmp = A
      A[j + 1] = A[j]
      A[j] = tmp
    end
  end
end

#just printing the array
A.each do |i|
  print i
end

gets()
```

Does someone know why does it happen? I just don't know where is the `nil` element.

I've tried everything, I know but I'm learning and I can't find the error.

Thanks for your help, also there is another little problem, when I try to make the `for` loop it doesn't work, it's not a big deal because there are more than one way to make the same thing, but still...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `i = 4` and `j = i + 1 #=> 5`, you attempt to execute

```
A[j] > A[j + 1]
```

which evaluates to

```
A[4] > A[5]
```

then to

```
2 > nil
```

This raises the exception, because `2.class #=> Fixnum` and [Fixnum#>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-3E) requires `>`'s argument to be numeric. In Ruby v2.4+ `Fixnum` methods have been converted to `Integer` methods (e.g., [Integer#>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-3E)).